# bad audio mic recording quality with ffmpeg compared to sox

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg

I am contacting you as after 3 days of searching I am stuck on a really simple point.

I want to record the sound of my mic on MacOS using ffmpeg.

I managed to do it using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -audio_device_index 2 -i "none:-" -c:a pcm_s32l alexspeaking.wav -y -loglevel debug
```

The issue is that each time I am speaking, there are cracks and pop in the sound...

I tried to use sox and it gave me a perfect and crystal clear sound and I have no idea why... Below is the output of the sox command :

```
sox -t coreaudio "G935 Gaming Headset" toto.wav -V6
sox:      SoX v
time:     Nov 15 2020 01:06:02
uname:    Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
compiler: gcc Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
arch:     1288 48 88 L
sox INFO coreaudio: Found Audio Device "DELL U2721DE"
sox INFO coreaudio: Found Audio Device "G935 Gaming "
sox DBUG coreaudio: audio device did not accept 2 channels. Use 1 channels instead.
sox DBUG coreaudio: audio device did not accept 44100 sample rate. Use 48000 instead.
Input File     : 'G935 Gaming Headset' (coreaudio)
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 32-bit
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Signed Integer PCM
Endian Type    : little
Reverse Nibbles: no
Reverse Bits   : no
sox INFO sox: Overwriting `toto.wav'
sox DBUG wav: Writing Wave file: Microsoft PCM format, 1 channel, 48000 samp/sec
sox DBUG wav:         192000 byte/sec, 4 block align, 32 bits/samp
Output File    : 'toto.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 32-bit
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Signed Integer PCM
Endian Type    : little
Reverse Nibbles: no
Reverse Bits   : no
Comment        : 'Processed by SoX'
sox DBUG effects: sox_add_effect: extending effects table, new size = 8
sox INFO sox: effects chain: input        48000Hz  1 channels (multi) 32 bits unknown length
sox INFO sox: effects chain: output       48000Hz  1 channels (multi) 32 bits unknown length
sox DBUG sox: start-up time = 0.051332
In:0.00% 00:00:07.13 [00:00:00.00] Out:340k  [      |      ]        Clip:0    ^C
sox DBUG input: output buffer still held 2048 samples; dropped.
Aborted.
sox DBUG wav: Finished writing Wave file, 1359872 data bytes 339968 samples
```

I am pretty sure the issue is linked to the way the encoding is done and the params I used with ffmpeg but I don't seem to be able to grasp which one I must use.

Any ideas if there are ffmpeg experts here ?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -audio_device_index 2 -i "none:-" -c:a copy alexspeaking.wav -y`

Comment: Sadly the result is the same. You can hear a sound recorder from youtube for instance. There are a lot of pop and cracking. No idea why... I suspect this may be linked to avfondation... https://share.getcloudapp.com/OAuQoZv8

Sound starts at 3 seconds

Comment: I've spent a whole day trying to solve the same problem. I think there is something wrong with ffmpeg's avfoundation on mac. There is a bug on the ffmpeg tracker from two weeks ago. I am now also trying to figure out how to pipe sox (which uses coreaudio) to ffmpeg for rtmp streaming. I documented my problems with choppy/jittery/distorted audio here: https://old.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/z86y3j/help_choppy_audio_with_ffmpeg_flv_for_rtmp_server/

Increasing the thread_queue_size helped, but does not eliminate the issue. Increasing priority with renice -20 <ffmpegpid> did not work either.